# VS 2015 error list does not jump to MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I always have my ASP.NET MVC projects set to compile views, using the following tag, so any errors in views will appear in the Error List.

```
<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
```

One of the most efficient debugging methods with VS is to double-click the items in the Error List and be taken to exactly the line where the compile error has been found.

With my previous VS 2010, this worked fine for code files and views.

Since VS 2015, this still works for code files, but no longer seems to work for views, regardless of whether they are aspx or cshtml.  There is no error message, just a non-response to the double-click.

Any ideas what the problem is or how I should approach troubleshooting?  This one has me beat, searches have turned up very little, and it's a real drag to have to open and navigate views manually to find the error locations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, still no solution, but I found an acceptable workaround for the time being, just in case anyone else is having this problem.

The text error listings in the Output window can also be double-clicked to be taken the file and location, and this actually does work for views as well as code files.  Go figure.

Using this method, the Error List appearing at the end of a compile is now just an annoyance, so this can be switched off with

> Toools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Always show Error List if
>   build finishes with errors

Comment: I have checked this in 2017 and I didn't see it work at all. still see no error when I have modified my code in c#.